# Python GUI2Exe Application Standalone Build (Using Py2Exe)

Tags: python, selenium, py2exe, gui2exe, python-standalone

I am trying to build a Python Script into a stand alone application.  I am using GUI2Exe.  My script uses selenium package.  I have it installed.
Project compiles fine and runs on python command line directly but fails to build a stand alone because it is referring to folder:

```
 ERROR: test_file_data_extract (__main__.FileDataExtract)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "File_data_extract.py", line 18, in setUp
  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.pyc", line 63, in     __init__
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\users\\username\\PycharmProjects\\Python_27_32bit\\file_data_extract\\dist\\File_data_extract.exe\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'
```

It is looking for selenium package is located at :
C:\Users\username\Anaconda2_Py27_32bit\Lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox

where  C:\Users\username\Anaconda2_Py27_32bit is where I installed Anaconda Python 2.7, 32 bit version.  By default it is looking for in \dist\filename.exe folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build it using bbfreeze. It works great.

First I had to install bbfreezee via pip (one time only):

```
pip install bbfreeze
```

Create a build_package.py file as:

```
from bbfreeze import Freezer
f = Freezer("project_name", includes=("selenium","SendKeys",)) #list problem packages here to manually include
f.addScript("project_name_script.py")
f()    # starts the freezing process
```

Build project:

```
python build_package.py bdist_bbfreezee
```

in folder project_name where project_name_script.py sits you find project_name_script.exe with all the include packages including selenium and sendkeys.  When you distribute the package you need to distribute entire project_name because it contains all dependent library dlls (python .pyd).

More details refer official bbfreezee here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/#downloads